# What is the correct way to push jsx with embedded js variables on to an array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react and I'm a little confused. I have a component called CardList.js, which displays a list of cards. It gives the Card.js component that I have an object called card, and the Card.js reads through the object and displays the key value pairs it finds in an unordered list. I want Card.js to return an array of list items with js values inside the li tags.

I can't seem to get this right so there must be some detail I don't understand yet. Can I even do what I am attempting and it's just a minor typo, or am I misunderstanding and doing it completely wrong?

I've tried debugger, google and stack overflow, but I couldn't seem to find an example like mine where it is pushing a combination of jsx and js on to an array

Currently there is an error message "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" and it points to ending semicolon of cardJsx.push statement within for loop of Card.js, but I think the problem is more than that.

**CardList.js**

```
import Card from './Card';

debugger;
const CardList = ({cardList}) => <div>{cardList.map((card, i) => <Card id={i} card={card} />)}</div>;
export default CardList;
```

**Card.js**

```
const Card = ({id, card}) => {
    debugger;
    const cardJsx = [<ul class="list-group">];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(card)) {
        cardJsx.push(<li className="list-group-item">{key}: {value} </li>); // semicolon is where error message points to
    }
    cardJsx.push(</ul>);
    return <div>{cardJsx}</div>;
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding different types of components on `cardJsx`. You may create an array of elements, but they should be the same element.
You can see that [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/rERgyY).

Comment: I did not know that <ul> and <li> are treated as components let alone different ones. I think of components as pointing to a js component file, not html or Jsx tags, but what you offered worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you iterate on `cardList` using `map`, your `Card` component is generating new set of `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` element which is wrong. you must have only 1 parent `<ul></ul>` and in `Card` component you can have multiple `<li>...</li>` elements.

You can try this,

```
const CardList = ({cardList}) => (
  <div>
    <ul className="list-group"> //Add `ul` element here only
      {cardList.map((card, i) => (
        <Card id={i} card={card} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

And your `Card` component should be,

```
const Card = ({id, card}) => {
  debugger
  const cardJsx = []
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(card)) {
    cardJsx.push(
      <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
        {key}:{value}
      </li>
    )
  }
  return <>{cardJsx}</> //Don't use `div` here instead you can use `Fragments`
}

export default Card
```

Simplified [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-sfooo?fontsize=14).

Refer [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

**Update**

As per this requirement,

> Card has to return  because Cardlist that invokes it is creating a list of lists, so Card needs to return a single list each time CardList invokes it.

You can do this,

```
const CardList = ({cardList}) => (
  <div>
      {cardList.map((card, i) => (
        <Card id={i} card={card} />
      ))}
  </div>
)
```

And `Card` component is,

```
const Card = ({id, card}) => {
  debugger
  const cardJsx = []
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(card)) {
    cardJsx.push(
      <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
        {key}:{value}
      </li>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="list-group">{cardJsx}</ul> //You need to add your parent `ul` tag here
    </>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: Card has to return <ul> because Cardlist that invokes it is creating an array of lists, so Card needs to return a single list each time CardList invokes it. – Bobh 15 mins ago